# How can I determine which rows have a duplicate value in a column using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase]
(
    [PhraseId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English] NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    [Romaji] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
)
```

I tried to add a unique index to the `English` column but it fails as there are duplicates. How can I find out which are duplicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested query finds `English` values that are in 2 or more rows. The outer query returns the rows that have `English` values in the nested query.

A nested query is required here because you probably want to get the `PhraseId` and if you `group by English` to get duplicate values, then `PhraseId` is lost.

```
select *
from Phrase
where English in
  (select English
  from Phrase
  group by English
  having count(*) > 1)
order by English
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With dupes
as
(select *,row_number() over (partition by english order by (select null)) as rownum
from table)
select * from cte where rownum>1
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.